Why must one be at the gate at least 60 minutes before departure when flying from Guam (GUM) to Honolulu (HNL) with United?
One must (mirror) be at the gate at least 60 minutes before departure when flying from Guam (GUM) to Honolulu (HNL) with United. Why?
I believe that HON is the only US airport that United fly to from GUM, but one typically doesn't have be at the gate at least 60 minutes before departure when flying to a US airport.

Personal opinion: the size or airport and kind of operations: it is not a huge international airport with a lot of staff (but with some large aircraft arriving from time to time). So thing go slower (less staff, few resources). And cargo is also important (mails, etc.): so earlier they get data of all passengers, better they can sell extra (fast) cargo slots. -- But just opinions without any strong source

I've had experiences where flights left early. I can't know what happened behind the scenes for them to consider that alright (did absolutely everyone that checked in show up? or do they guess who is at the airport based on who got their ticket at airport, who dropped their luggage, who scanned their ticket at security?), but it can happen. Note that they don't have to do a last call.

FYI: I have flown an UA from Brussels to the US quite a few times and I don't think I have ever shown up at the gate that early. I wasn't even aware of that list. Well, they took me anyway and no one has ever complained about it. The questions of "WHY" is often futile with airlines.  Could be  that "some thought it was a good idea and no one feels strongly enough to fight the bureaucracy over it"


one typically doesn't have be at the gate at least 60 minutes before departure when flying to a US airport.

Yes, one does. For most international flights to the US one must be at the gate 60 minutes before departure. See your own link.
Guam is not part of the United States (it's a US territory). Guam has its own immigration policy which is different from the US policy. As such, checks are necessary to ensure visitors to Guam who are ineligible to travel to the US do not board.

Guam is part of the United States.

@gerrit, no, it's a US unincorporated territory, not a State. More to the point, it has it's own immigration system which is distinctly separate from Hawaii & mainland US system.

It is not a state, but it is still a US territory, even if unincorporated, thus part of the US.  It is as much part of the US as Greenland is part of the Kingdom of Denmark.

@gerrit for purposes of domestic vs international flights, Guam is closer to an international flight. St Helena is a "british overseas territory" but even British citizens must go through immigration to enter.

"For most international flights one must be at the gate 60 minutes" that is simply not true. I fly a LOT internationally and I'm almost never at the gate that early.  This is ONLY required if you do a tedious doc check or security at the gate. Most doc checks are cursory, and just take a  few minutes , so need to go early.

@Hilmar to the US? I must admit, I find the United checks to be not at all cursory and in fact quite intrusive.

@gerrit I don't know about Danish internal structure, but Guam is not part of the US for a lot of purposes (including, in this case, immigration). Guam residents do not have representation in the US government (they have a delegate in the house of representatives, who cannot vote, have no senators, and have no electors in presidential elections). Generally, citizens of Guam are US citizens, but requirements to visit Guam are different from the US mainland. Similarly to Puerto Rico and Washington DC, although those two don't have separate immigration policies.

@littleadv: I currently live in the US so 90% of my international flights are from/to the US. I’m a United million miler and I probably have 100+ US bound United flights under my belt (or butt :). Typically boarding starts 50 minutes before the departure and ends 15 minutes before departure. I just pulled a random boarding pass LHR-BOS from my diary stack and that’s exactly what it says. If I have lounge access I go extra late and it’s never been a problem

@Hilmar if boarding starts 50 minutes prior it stands to reason that you're expected to be at the gate by that time. I fail to see the contradiction. You're saying that you're not physically at the gate 1 hour prior, and that may be true. But if you end up missing the flight because of that - that would be your fault and the airline won't owe you a thing (although they might, since you're such a valued customer, exercise discretion).

@littleadv: Nope. You need to be at the gate no later than the "boarding closes" time. As long as you show up 15 minutes before departure (or whatever your boarding pass says), they are legally required to take you and if they don't it's "involuntarily denied boarding". What's printed on the BP supersedes any other rules.

@littleadv: "Valued customer" has nothing to to do with it. United used to be utterly brutal: I once had a delayed incoming and had to sprint to the connecting gate but made it with 2 minutes to spare. Sweating and heaving I scanned by BP but it went red. Gate agent checked it and said "Oh Mr. X. We didn't think you would make it so we already gave your seat away !!" I had the highest earnable United status at the time (1k).

@littleadv: "it has it's own immigration system which is distinctly separate from Hawaii & mainland US system" No; Guam is under the same immigration system as the US, including the same green card, naturalization processes, and nonimmigrant visas. Guam is part of the "United States" for the purposes of the Immigration and Nationality Act. The only difference is the Guam-CNMI Visa Waiver Program, which allows additional visa waiver countries.

@user102008 so... not the same. Which is the point.

Your link includes the answer to your question.

At the following airports, there may be extra security or
documentation checks. Because of that you need to be at the gate at a
specific time before departure:

Brussels (BRU): 60 minutes
Dublin (DUB): 30 minutes
Guam (GUM) to Honolulu (HNL): 60 minutes
Koror (ROR): 60 minutes
Kosrae (KSA): 60 minutes
Kwajalein (KWA): 60 minutes
Lima (LIM): 30 minutes
Majuro (MAJ): 60 minutes
Pohnpei (PNI): 60 minutes
Sydney (SYD): 60 minutes
Truk (TKK): 60 minutes
Yap (YAP): 60 minutes



Why are there "extra security or documentation checks" when flying from Guam (GUM) to Honolulu (HNL)?

Curious that Dublin is only 30 minutes.  I guess that it's because the Irish are nice people; along with the Peruvians.

@FranckDernoncourt US immigration checks.

@littleadv Thanks, one typically doesn't have be at the gate at least 60 minutes before departure when flying to a US airport. Why do US immigration checks take longer when flying from Guam (GUM) to Honolulu (HNL) with United?

@badjohn it's 15 minutes in most cases.

@FranckDernoncourt to the best of my knowledge yes, one does. Dublin seems to be an exception (probably because of the pre-clearance process, similarly to the Canadian airports).

@FranckDernoncourt oh, by the way, Guam is not part of the United States, it's a US territory. In case you didn't know.

@FranckDernoncourt I'm looking at the list in the answer: 30 for Dublin and Peru but 60 for the others.

@badjohn it's a list of  exceptions ("there may be extra security or documentation checks.")

@FranckDernoncourt Oh dear, so the Irish are not special - I always thought that we were.  I fell victim to confirmation bias.

@badjohn they are special, just not in this way.
